# LM317LZ LED driver circuit - wrong output current

Tags: led, constant-current

I built a minimal LED driver circuit using a LM317LZ and a 12 Ohm resistor between OUT and ADJ (identical to e.g. [Understanding this LM317 LED Driver circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181767/understanding-this-lm317-led-driver-circuit)). According to the datasheet this should give 100 mA output current but in fact it it is around 60 mA. Input voltage is about 40 V, the LED is a COB LEB which has aprox. 32 V forward voltage at 100 mA. The voltage drop across the resistor is 0.55 V. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the **real** voltage going to the LED when powered with your regulator?

Comment: @JRE about 29 V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LM317LZ has internal thermal overload protection. TO-92 can not dissipate 600 mW. (40-32-1.25)*0.1=0.675. Your chip overheated.

Comment: Good point. The datasheet just mentions that power dissipation is "internally limited". Thank you.

Comment: T0-92 can dissipate 150 mW in normal condition. Get in TO-220. If not enough, heat sink can be set

Comment: @user263983 Get a switcher if you need to drop that much voltage!